# Deleting results from subquery in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I messed up a database table and now have multiple duplicates in it. Now I want to delete all the duplicates. I found them all with the following query:

```
select order_uuid, changed_at, count(*)
from mobisl_1.t_order_states
group by order_uuid, changed_at
having count (*) > 1;
```

The duplicates are defined by the columns 'order_uuid' and 'changed_at'. If the combination of both appears more than once in the table, it is defined as a duplicate.

I get a result set of 904 rows. The result set is as I expected. Now I want to delete those duplicates with

```
delete from mobisl_1.t_order_states
where ORDER_UUID in (
    select order_uuid, changed_at, count(*)
    from mobisl_1.t_order_states
    group by order_uuid, changed_at
    having count (*) > 1
);
```

Oracle then displays Error ORA-00913: too many values. What can I do here? I already tried to limit the size of the result set with some condition (only get rows with date lower than x) but with no positive result.

Comment: Your sub-query returns 3 columns, but you're only comparing it to one column. However, if you fix that you will delete **all** duplicates, including the last one. I'd go with an EXISTS condition instead, making sure there's one row left.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use tuples and to remove the `count(*)` from the `select`:

```
delete
    from mobisl_1.t_order_states
where (ORDER_UUID, changed_at) in
         (select order_uuid, changed_at
          from mobisl_1.t_order_states
          group by order_uuid, changed_at
          having count(*) > 1
         );
```

This answers the question that you asked.  However, I don't think that is what you really want to do.  Normally, I would want to keep *one* of the rows with the duplicates.

If you want to keep one of the rows, then either do some research or ask another question.